# Start IntentService from fragment

Tags: android, intentservice

I'm trying to start an IntentService from a fragment tab but i have no responce. the code from my fragment is below:

```
private Intent prepareIntent(boolean isSending) {
    Intent localIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), StartIActivity.class);
    Log.d(THIS_FILE, "StartIActivity");
    localIntent.putExtra("incoming", isSending);
    localIntent.putExtra("remote_contact", setValidNumber(callUri));
    localIntent.putExtra("acc_id", this.accId);
    return localIntent;
}

private void startIAService(boolean bool) {
    Log.d(THIS_FILE, "Start Service");
    Context ctx = (Context) myFragment.this.getActivity();
    ctx.startService(prepareIntent(bool));
    return;
}
```

and my intent serviceclass is :

```
public class StartIActivity extends IntentService {
    public StartIActivity() {
        super("StartIActivity");
    }

    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent it) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(it);
        intent.setClass(this, Activity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        Log.d("IActivity", "Start Activity");
    }
}
```

When run startIAservice the prepereIntent is run but it can't start the service. I need to use IntentService because i want to execute one task at a time but i can't understand how.
Any help here and what is the best code implemenattion to do this?

Comment: have you added service to manifest?

Comment: Ohh! I forgot it. Thanx!! you make my day!!

Comment: One more question. Can you guide me if i want to encapsulate the intent into a synchronized try-finally block?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Declare service in manifest.xml